# Does Collecting Multiple Power Up Blocks Increase The Chance Of Getting A Good Powerup?

Tags: mario-kart-ds

I have had Mario Kart for a long time now and have enjoyed it a lot (except when those freaking red turtle shells come at me).  My question is about a habit that I have had when playing of trying to pick up multiple power up blocks if I have the chance thinking it will increase my chance of getting a good item.  I now want to find out if this actually does help my chances at all of getting a good item.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't know about MKDS specifically, but from experience with other entries in the series, I know that the only way to improve the quality of your powerups is by not being first. You only get the really cool powerups like the blue shell or the thunder when you're 6th or worse.

Comment: The only benefit to hitting multiple blocks I'm aware of is that you increase the chance of robbing someone (directly) behind you of an item for that section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The item you get is only determined by two things:

- Your placing the moment you touch the Item Box. Racers in front tend to get defensive items, while those in the back get offensive ones.
- Your kart's Items rating. Having a low rating will mean you get more Mushrooms, while having a high one will mean you get more shells.

Collecting multiple Item Boxes at once has no effect.